# Unsupported Linux Kernel on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel, support

While checking the support status on my Ubuntu Server, the currently used Kernel came up as unsupported:

```
x@x:~⟫ ubuntu-support-status --show-unsupported [...]
Unsupported: 
linux-headers-3.19.0-58 linux-headers-3.19.0-58-generic 
linux-image-3.19.0-58-generic linux-image-extra-3.19.0-58-generic
```

My system is up to date with `apt-get update, upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`

What exactly does that mean?